# Sending a token between classes

Tags: java, android, parsing, token

I would like to sending string between java class in android studio. I have class `CreateToken.java` and `MainActivity.java`, how can I send string `yourToken` to `MainActivity.java` and how can I receive string `yourToken` in MainActivity.java, and the result of `yourToken` is `com.example.user.application.CreateToken@yourToken` but `yourToken` is not full token, its just 7 charecter.

This is one of my function in `CreateToken.java`:

```
public class CreateToken {
private ICreateToken listener;

public CreateToken(ICreateToken listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public Call<Token> api(final Context ctx){
    ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String usernameApi = "web";
    String passwordApi = "123";
    Call<Token> getToken = api.postWebService(usernameApi,passwordApi);
    getToken.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
            String error = response.body().getError();
            if (error.equals("false")){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, response.body().getToken(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Smart","Response : Token Show");
                String yourToken =  response.body().getToken();
                listener.onTokenGenerated(yourToken);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Smart","Response : Token NUll");
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Smart","Response : Token Null");

        }
    });
    return getToken;
}
public interface ICreateToken {
    void onTokenGenerated(String token);
}
}
```

And this is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CreateToken.ICreateToken {

    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                   CreateToken token = new CreateToken(MainActivity.this);
                   textView.setText(token.toString());
     }

    @Override
    public void onTokenGenerated(String token) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what the issue here ? You already pass string using interface

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to call the api method with `token.api(MainActivity.this)` ?

Comment: where should i put token.api(MainActivity.this) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `api` like below for sending request to server:

```
CreateToken tokenCreator = new CreateToken(MainActivity.this);
tokenCreator.api(this);
```

and wait to triggered `onTokenGenerated` and using `String token`

```
@Override
public void onTokenGenerated(String token) {
    textView.setText(token.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to `yourToken` in `MainActivity` in

```
    @Override
    public void onTokenGenerated(String token) {

    }
```

when `listener.onTokenGenerated(yourToken);` in `CreateToken` is executed. Just call `public Call<Token> api(final Context ctx)` method, and receive your token in `MainActivity`.